# Unable to run flink jar : Multiple factories for identifier 'default' that implement

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I was using the below mentioned POM file for writing the flink code

```
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Flink Quickstart Job</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <flink.version>1.15.0</flink.version>
        <target.java.version>1.8</target.java.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${target.java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${target.java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <log4j.version>2.17.1</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Apache Flink dependencies -->
        <!-- These dependencies are provided, because they should not be packaged into the JAR file. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add connector dependencies here. They must be in the default scope (compile). -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.26</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>flink-table</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.15.0</version>-->
<!--            <type>pom</type>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-java-bridge</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-scala-bridge_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-planner_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-files</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Add logging framework, to produce console output when running in the IDE. -->
        <!-- These dependencies are excluded from the application JAR by default. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-data-lake-store-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20220320</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Java Compiler -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${target.java.version}</source>
                    <target>${target.java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- We use the maven-shade plugin to create a fat jar that contains all necessary dependencies. -->
            <!-- Change the value of <mainClass>...</mainClass> if your program entry point changes. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-force-shading</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.logging.log4j:*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
                                    Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>tableAPI.GettingStartedTable</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <!-- This improves the out-of-the-box experience in Eclipse by resolving some warnings. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.1.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>shade</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

While running the jar file in flink cluster I am getting the following error.

```
The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Multiple factories for identifier 'default' that implement 'org.apache.flink.table.delegation.ExecutorFactory' found in the classpath.

Ambiguous factory classes are:

org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.DefaultExecutorFactory
org.apache.flink.table.planner.loader.DelegateExecutorFactory
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:836)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:247)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1078)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1156)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1156)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Multiple factories for identifier 'default' that implement 'org.apache.flink.table.delegation.ExecutorFactory' found in the classpath.

Ambiguous factory classes are:

org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.DefaultExecutorFactory
org.apache.flink.table.planner.loader.DelegateExecutorFactory
    at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.discoverFactory(FactoryUtil.java:553)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.create(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:276)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment.create(TableEnvironment.java:93)
    at tableAPI.GettingStartedTable.main(GettingStartedTable.java:17)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
    ... 8 more
```

Using flink 1.15. I was able to run the code inside my IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set some dependencies scope as `provided` so they are not included in the JAR to avoid conflicts, that is most likely the issue. You actually have a comment in your POM:

```
<!-- These dependencies are provided, because they should not be packaged into the JAR file. -->
```

See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/configuration/overview/#flink-apis to see the list of runtime dependencies that should be set as provided and https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/project-configuration/#setting-up-a-project-basic-dependencies for some more details